# Slow automatization of the results

Tags: excel, format, conditional-formatting

My excel file is not working properly, since it takes more then a minute to sum 1+2. I deleted all conditional formating, but the problem remains. I didn't use VLOOKUP formulas as well, since i read that can cause troubles as well.

the file is located here - [LINK](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3469940/excel-helponmodel.xlsx)

I will be gratefull for any kind of feedback!!!

G

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't download the file since I'm at work, and I can't comment as well because I don't have 50 reputation.

Avoid volatile functions if possible. Excel recalculates these functions with each recalculation, even if nothing has changed. Too many volatile functions (RAND(), NOW(), TODAY(), and so on) can slow things down.

I don't know if this is the case but it helped me when I had alot of formulas on a sheet.

Comment: Out of this, i do use ROW() in order to define a row number

Comment: I mentioned NOW, not ROW. 

Try reducing the number of references in each formula to the bare minimum. Copied formulas are notorious for repeating references and calculations. Move repeated calculations to a cell and reference that cell in the original formula.

Comment: The problem remains though. I just can't find the core of this problem

Comment: Try using manual calculation mode and see what happens when you press f9

Comment: The same. It takes a lot of time for excel to process the content of the cell even. Only after it starts calculating, which is seen below in the processor usage.. If it's not too much trouble, i'd be really gratefull if u could take a look at it

Comment: As I previously stated, i'm in work right now and I'm not able to see your project, I would only be able to see it in about 5 hours so let's hope someone who can actually pin this issue out arrives. Best regards man.